# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I keep getting an index out of range exception. Must not be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Problem is when I check `toRemove` the count is lower than than respondents. So how is this error occurring? If 5 are in `respondents` and `toRemove` is only 3 then how is this error occurring?

```
var respondents = RespondentRepository.GetRespondents(UserSession, fieldsToInclude);

// iterate through the respondents. If search query not like results throw the result away.
List<int> toRemove = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < respondents.Count; i++)
{
    if (!respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Any())
        toRemove.Add(i);
    else
    {
        bool checkSingleEmail = false;
        bool checkAllEmails = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count; j++)
        {
            checkSingleEmail = respondents[i].EmailAddresses[j].Address.ToString().Contains(query);

            if (checkSingleEmail == true)
                checkAllEmails = true;

            if (respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count == 1 && j == 0 && checkAllEmails == false)
                toRemove.Add(i);
            else if (checkAllEmails == false && j+1 == respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count)
                toRemove.Add(i);
        }
    }
}

foreach (var respRemove in toRemove)
{
    respondents.RemoveAt(respRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to work with indexes, you can write it this way :

```
foreach (var respRemove in toRemove.OrderByDesc(r => r).ToList())
{
    respondents.RemoveAt(respRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception occurs because you remove items from the list and then assume that the other items are still at the same index. Try keeping a reference to the item instead:

```
var respondents = RespondentRepository.GetRespondents(UserSession, fieldsToInclude);

                // iterate through the respondents. If search query not like results throw the result away.
                List<Respondent> toRemove = new List<Respondent>();
                for (int i = 0; i < respondents.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Any())
                        toRemove.Add(respondents[i]);
                    else
                    {
                        bool checkSingleEmail = false;
                        bool checkAllEmails = false;
                        for (int j = 0; j < respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count; j++)
                        {
                            checkSingleEmail = respondents[i].EmailAddresses[j].Address.ToString().Contains(query);

                            if (checkSingleEmail == true)
                                checkAllEmails = true;

                            if (respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count == 1 && j == 0 && checkAllEmails == false)
                                toRemove.Add(respondents[i]);
                            else if (checkAllEmails == false && j+1 == respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count)
                                toRemove.Add(respondents[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var respRemove in toRemove)
                {
                    respondents.Remove(respRemove);
                }
```

For instance the last item may be at index 4 to begin with. But if you remove index 3, then it is now at index 3 and index 4 does not exist.

Comment: +1 oskar, you said more or less the same as myself :)

Comment: When I try to use the above respRemove foreach I get an error with repondents.Remove(respRemove). The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.

Comment: List<Respondent> respondent = new List<Respondent>() that is what I would assume the var is transforming it into

Comment: Assume? Probably not if the list is containing Respondent. Did you change the type of toRemove as well?

Answer (score 2):

you need to change:

```
respondents.RemoveAt(respRemove);
```

to

```
respondents.Remove(respRemove);
```

this is due to `RemoveAt()` being tied to an index, and as that item has been removed, the command becomes invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of toRemove before removing.  Then the indexes of the remaining items are preserved after each removal.

```
toRemove.Reverse();

foreach (int respRemove in toRemove)
{
    respondents.RemoveAt(respRemove);
}
```

The other thing to watch out for, is if i is being added more than once:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < respondents[i].EmailAddresses.Count; j++)
    {
       ...
            toRemove.Add(i);
```

Don't let i get added to toRemove more than once.

Comment: For instance index 4 in respondents (if there are 5 items) will not exist, even if you delete at index 0 first

Comment: That's why you remove 4, then 0.